# 仮想マシンでテーブルをGUIで確認する方法はありますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

パソコンの環境

- windows10
- Vagrant
- VirtualBOX
- putty
- Cyberdug

ドットインストールで仮想開発環境を構築しました。

Railsのhas_secure_passwordでちゃんとパスワードが暗号化されているか確認したいです。

データベースをＧＵＩでみれるソフトがあるそうなんですが、そもそも仮想開発環境だから使えないでしょうか？

Comment: 仮想環境はXなしの構成でしょうか？

Comment: 仮想マシンの詳しい情報(OSの種類など)があるとより現実的な回答が付くと思います。(その辺りも踏まえてクロスプラットフォーム対応のアプリを回答したのですが…)

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteのデータを確認したいということであれば、クロスプラットフォーム対応の
「DB Browser for SQLite」などがあります。

[DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org)
[“SQLite”のデータベースを管理できる「SQLite Database Browser」 - 窓の杜](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/review/410527.html)

Answer (score -1):

**自己解決**

仮想マシンからデータベースファイルをダウンロードし
DB Browser for SQLiteで開く。

わたしと同じ環境ならCyberduckをつかって仮想マシンからデータベースファイルをダウンロードする。

もっといいやり方があれば教えてください

---

あとあとわかったことだが、暗号化されたパスワードが作成されたか確認するためにわざわざ上記ソフトをインストール必要はないドットインストールで環境構築したらならsqliteが入っているはず。